# Help in understanding Store Word (SW) instruction in Risc-V

Tags: microprocessor, assembly, processor, risc-v

So this is what I understood from what my professor said, but I don't think it's the right answer. What am I doing wrong? I'm sure It's just some small thing that I'm getting mixed up.

Given instruction: **SW x8, -6(x4)**

What I thought it meant: Take the content of source register **x8** and subtract **6** from it. The result gives the memory address. Now, store the content of register **x4** into the obtained memory address.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is actually about the assembler code, not the electrical engineering behind CPUs. This is, in the best and positive sense, a candidate for Stackoverflow.com, not electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: How can you read the description of this instruction that way??? Can you provide a link to the documentation you are reading? Or a link to the textbook? The ones I have are very clear and very easy to understand. And your writing doesn't look much like it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Computer Architecture, ISA related, processor assembly code questions, they have always been welcome and well answered by EESE community over the years.

Answer (score 6):

With RISC-V assembler, the operand order is destination/source [except for stores](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59802318/427158).

Thus, your example instruction reads:

```
       
SW x8, -6(x4)
   ^     ^
   |     |
   |   destination
   source
```

The store word (`sw`) instruction reads the lower 4 bytes of your source register and stores them into memory at the address given in the destination operand.

In your example, `-6(x4)` is the usual assembler syntax for specifying a register where an address is stored (`x4`)  and a constant offset (`-6`) to that address.

In prose your example instruction reads:

> Store the lower 4 bytes located in register x8 into memory at the address obtained by subtracting 6 from the address that is located in register x4.

More formally:

```
sw src, off(dst) => M[dst + off] = src[31:0]
```

See also for example Annex A RISC-V Instruction Listings, page 162 of [The RISC-V Reader](http://riscvbook.com/) by Patterson and Waterman, 2017.